# Plot area too short for Y axis (base graphics)

Tags: r

I have created this `data frame`:

```
seq(1,70)
Group <-paste("a", 1:70, sep="")
Counts <- c(1:18, 5:14, 1:20, 5:20, 10:15)
```

When plotted, it returns a large plot where `"Group"` does not fit:

```
barplot(Counts, names.arg=Group, 
        horiz=TRUE, las=1, cex.names=0.6, border=NA,
        ylim=c(0,30), xlim=c(0,20), width = 1.5)
```

EDIT: this is the plot after deleting  `ylim=c(0,30)`

[image]

I would like to be able to see each term on the "Group" axis.

Answer (score 0):

The `ylim` argument is constraining how many groups are shown.  Remove it and you can see all of them.

Comment: He can also set `ylim=c(0,105)` or `ylim=c(0,110)` in this case so it will have more spacing between the plots.  Also, the margins can be controlled with `par(mai=c(1,1,0,1))` if he wants more space at the top.

Comment: @user1362215: that is correct.  I think in this case, there is no need for the `ylim` statement.

Comment: After trying both suggestions, I still can't see the y axis clearly

Comment: @Christopher Louden: the terms are not legible

Comment: What resolution are you trying to view it at?  It's not always possible to make a graph really small and view it, too.

Comment: When you output the png, make the `height` argument larger, say `480*4`.  It looks like yours is squished down.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
barplot(stage1_90$Percentage.stage1, 
        names.arg=stage1_90$miR.stage1, 
        horiz=TRUE, las=1, cex.names=0.5, border=NA,
        ylim=c(0,125), xlim=c(0,14), main = "Stage 1. Top 90%",
        xlab = "% total expression", space = 1, yaxs = "i")
```

And then I printed out in A4 format